# How to properly create a JPQL Query using Hibernate 5 (Query type is deprecated)

Tags: hibernate, jpql, dao, deprecated

I'm using Hibernate 5.5 and I'm getting trouble to make queries with deprecated types in a generic DAO that was made with an old version of Hibernate.

My `createQuery` method in the generic dao class:

```java
protected Query<?> createQuery(String query) {
    return getSession().createQuery(query);
}
```

No deprecated alert in this method but when I'm going to use it in this code I get deprecated alert messages:

```java
//find a user by name
public List<User> findByName(String name){
    Query<User> q = getSession().createQuery("from User where lower(nome) like lower(?)");
    q.setString(0, "%" + name +"%");
    return q.list();
}
```

Here I'm getting deprecated alert in the type `Query` and its `list()` method.

To not create another question with the same subject, I'm also getting deprecated alert in this other method of the generic dao:

```java
protected Criteria createCriteria() {
    return getSession().createCriteria(this.clazz);
}
```

Here the method `createCriteria` is also deprecated.

(the `getSession` method returns the current session of the hibernate `SessionFactory` class)

What I want to know is how can I update this codes, using hibernate 5 so I don't get deprecated alerts.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm getting deprecated alert in the type Query and its list() method.

I would suggest you to rewrite your query in the following way:

```java
public List<User> findByName(String name) {
   TypedQuery<User> query = session.createQuery(
       "select u from User u " +
       "where lower(u.nome) like lower('%' || :name || '%')", User.class);
   query.setParameter("name", name);
   return query.getResultList();
}
```

Notes:

1. You should use `TypedQuery` instead of the deprecated `Query`.
2. As it's noted in the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select):

> *Even though HQL does not require the presence of a `select_clause`, it is generally good practice to include one.* For simple queries the intent is clear and so the intended result of the `select_clause` is easy to infer. But on more complex queries that is not always the case.
>
> It is usually better to explicitly specify intent. *Hibernate does not actually enforce that a `select_clause` be present even when parsing JPQL queries, however, applications interested in JPA portability should take heed of this.*

3. I would suggest you to use *named parameters* instead of *positional parameters* as more readable.

As for `Criteria` query, look at [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria) of the documentation.